# AWS Amplify IndexedDB Exposes too much data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I recently deployed my application to Production and noticed that the IndexedDB was exposed from the dev tools. This was concerning as all of my tables and the data from within them are present. Is there something I can do to fix this or at least encrypt/hide while in production?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.